# Add a sql like clause to Filter function

Tags: filter

This is a function of a collection.php

```
public function setAvailableFilter($customerGroupId, $websiteId, $date = null, $sku=null)
{
    if (is_null($date)) {
        $date = now(true);
    }
    $this->addFieldToFilter('website_ids', array('finset' => $websiteId))
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_ids', array('finset' => $customerGroupId))
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $this->getSelect()->where("(from_date IS NULL) OR (DATE(from_date) <= ?)", $date)
        ->where("(to_date IS NULL) OR (DATE(to_date) >= ?)", $date)
        ->where(" conditions_serialized like '%?%'", $sku)
        ->order('sort_order DESC');
    return $this;
}
```

i added this ->where("conditions_serialized like '%?%'", $sku) but seems produce errors, any one know what the problem about the where clause?

Comment: error message??

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare themeOptions() (previously declared in /var/www/second/app/design/frontend/default/metroshop/template/page/html/head.phtml:4) in /var/www/second/app/design/frontend/default/metroshop/template/page/html/head.phtml on line 145

completely unrelated error message

Comment: Have you tried setting the theme back to the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add like clause then follow the below code.

$collection->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $name . '%'));

Hope you got the solutions.

for more [reference](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/)